# Undefined index php, checking the date, multilangue option

Tags: php

i'm Ania and I am new to forum it's great to find a place like this!!! I just started my adventure with programming and hope from now on it will only get better and better ^ ^.

So i'm working on one assignment,

```
    <form method="post" action="date_multilangue.php">

<input type="text" length="10" name="date" > <br> <br>


    <select name="lang" >
        <option value="fr" selected> Français </option>
        <option value="en"> Anglais </option>
    </select>

    <br> <br>

    <input type="submit" value="Soumettre">
```

Now my php file :

```
 <html>
<head>
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" text="#000000">
<?php

$date = $_POST['date'];


$langue = $_POST['lang'];

$date_explose = implode("-",explode("/", $date) );

global $ts;

$ts = strtotime($date_explose);

function verif_date($date_saisie) {

    $date = explode("/",$date_saisie); // On récupère la date saisie

    // var_dump($date);

    // Pré contrôle des saisies de l'utilisateur avant vérification date
    if((count($date)==3) && (is_numeric($date[0])) && (is_numeric($date[1])) && (is_numeric($date[2])) )
    {
        // Vérification simple
        $jour = $date[0];
        $mois = $date[1];
        $annee = $date[2];

        if (checkdate($mois, $jour, $annee))
        { // La date est valide
            return true;
        } 
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
} // Fin de la fonction



function ladate($lang, $ts) {

    $jour_semaine = date("w", $ts);
    $jour_mois = date("j",$ts);
    $mois_numerique = date("n",$ts);
    $annee = date("Y",$ts);

        $jour['fr'] = array("Dimanche","Lundi", "Mardi", "Mercredi", "Jeudi", "Vendredi", "Samedi");

        $mois['fr'] = array(1 => "janvier", "février", "mars", "avril", "mai", "juin", "juillet", "août", "septembre", "octobre", "novembre", "décembre");

        $jour['us'] = array("Sunday","Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday");

        $mois['us'] = array(1 => "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");

    $intro = "";
    if ($langue == 'fr') {
            $intro .= "La date est le";
        } elseif ($langue == ' en') {
            $intro .= "The date is";
        }
        echo " $intro" . " {$jour[$lang][$jour_semaine]} $jour_mois {$mois[$lang][$mois_numerique]} $annee";

        echo "<br/>";
}

if(verif_date($date)) {
    ladate($langue, $ts);
}
```

When i submit the form i get the error :

```
 Notice: Undefined index: en in C:\wamp\www\php_imapp\exo_seance11\date_multilangue.php on line 74
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0004  257304  {main}( )   ..\date_multilangue.php:0
2   0.0005  258272  ladate( )   ..\date_multilangue.php:80
```

I would be  realy grateful if you could give me any suggestions how to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance!

line 74:

```
echo " $intro" . " {$jour[$lang][$jour_semaine]} $jour_mois {$mois[$lang][$mois_numerique]} $annee";
```

Comment: `if ($langue = 'fr') {` should be `if ($langue == 'fr') {`. `elseif ($langue ='en')` should be `elseif ($langue =='en')`

Comment: You might also want to post any additional code that you have and also point out which one is line 74.

Comment: Hey, thank u so much for your help! also im sorry i accidentally copied the code that i tried to debug, just changed it to original version and highlighted the line 74!

Comment: What errors you get after making the changes that I suggested ?

Comment: I changed the code and i get : undefiend variable '$langue' its on the line : if ($langue == 'fr')

Comment: Change `$langue` to `$lang`

Comment: I changed $langue to $lang everywhere but i still get Undefined index on line : echo " $intro" . " {$jour[$lang][$jour_semaine]} $jour_mois {$mois[$lang][$mois_numerique]} $annee";

Comment: Hey! Thank you Maximus2012 for your help! I finally debugged the code! it was the vallue of key arrays $jour['us'] and $mois['us'] that had to be changed for 'en' and also i accidentaly hit the space before 'ene on the if statement at the end!

Answer (score 0):

This is the right code for php :

```
    <?php


 $date = $_POST['date'];

 $lang = $_POST['lang'];


    $date_explose = implode("-",explode("/", $date) );

    global $ts;

    $ts = strtotime($date_explose);

    function verif_date($date_saisie) {

        $date = explode("/",$date_saisie); // On récupère la date saisie

        // var_dump($date);

        // Pré contrôle des saisies de l'utilisateur avant vérification date
        if((count($date)==3) && (is_numeric($date[0])) && (is_numeric($date[1])) && (is_numeric($date[2])) )
        {
            // Vérification simple
            $jour = $date[0];
            $mois = $date[1];
            $annee = $date[2];

            if (checkdate($mois, $jour, $annee))
            { // La date est valide
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    } // Fin de la fonction



    function ladate($lang, $ts) {

        $langue = $_POST['lang'];

        $jour_semaine = date("w", $ts);
        $jour_mois = date("j",$ts);
        $mois_numerique = date("n",$ts);
        $annee = date("Y",$ts);

        $jour['fr'] = array("Dimanche","Lundi", "Mardi", "Mercredi", "Jeudi", "Vendredi", "Samedi");

        $mois['fr'] = array(1 => "janvier", "février", "mars", "avril", "mai", "juin", "juillet", "août", "septembre", "octobre", "novembre", "décembre");

        $jour['en'] = array("Sunday","Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday");

        $mois['en'] = array(1 => "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");

        $intro = "";
        if ($lang == 'fr') {
            $intro = "La date est le";
        } elseif ($lang == 'en') {
            $intro = "The date is";
        }
        echo " $intro" . " {$jour[$lang][$jour_semaine]} $jour_mois {$mois[$lang][$mois_numerique]} $annee";

        echo "<br/>";
    }


    if(verif_date($date)) {
        ladate($lang, $ts);
    }
?>
```

Comment: which lines did you changed. Please provide where owner of this question did mistakes?